# react-native-popup-ui changing styles inside popup

Tags: react-native

I want to use simple popup in my app and found this library: https://github.com/RafaelAugustoS/react-native-popup-ui

Is there a way, to styles for example text inside `Popup.show()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles are hard coded into the component. You can see it in the source code [here](https://github.com/RafaelAugustoS/react-native-popup-ui/blob/408953635f6d1c280ece5ac4c773cf834bfe98de/src/basic/Popup/index.js#L193).

If you want to customize it, you will have to fork the repo and allow passing in the styles, or set the styles to what you need.

If you want to use the repo but change only the styles, you can use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) which would allow you to customize only the part of the plugin that you want.